# Can we use CFA (confirmatory factor analysis) to ascertain validity coefficient?

Tags: cross-validation, confirmatory-factor, validity

Validity coefficient is an important measure for test development especially in psychology and sociology wherein we have too indirect measurements. Perhaps we have different ways to know its size.

Comment: So what is the question? Please give more details.

Comment: I am interested in knowing whether we can get an estimate of the validity coefficient with the help of CFA ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, CFA is useful for validity coefficient estimation. Here's a quote from [Evaluation of convergent and discriminant validity with multitrait-multimethod correlations](http://www.statmodel.com/download/CDVC_LVM_BJMSP.pdf) ([Raykov, 2011](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1348/000711009X478616/abstract)):

> In order to point and interval estimate these three types of validity coefficients, a
>   special confirmatory factor analysis (CFA) model can be used in a first step (Kühnel,
>   1988). This model differs from popular CFA approaches to examining convergent and
>   discriminant validity, which have been available for more than two decades (e.g.,
>   Bagozzi & Yi, 1993; Marsh & Hocevar, 1983; Marsh, 1989; Eid, 2000), in one main
>   feature. This is the fact that in the cited procedures use is made of ‘proper’ latent
>   variables that are evaluated by multiple indicators. The latter are the collected multiple
>   measures of several traits using several methods of evaluation, whereas the latent
>   variables represent the traits themselves and somewhat more difficult to interpret latent
>   constructs. These constructs have been included in part to explain residual variation
>   among measures of the same trait with different modes of assessment, and have been
>   frequently referred to as ‘method factors’ (e.g., Marsh & Hocevar, 1983).

There's plenty more relevant info in this article after this section, so I won't quote it here, but do check it out!

**Reference**

Raykov, T. (2011). Evaluation of convergent and discriminant validity with multitrait–multimethod correlations. *British Journal of Mathematical and Statistical Psychology, 64*(1), 38–52.

Comment: Your answer is good. However, I am still not sure whether the measure of validity in this sense reflects a correction for measurement error in the sense of reliability or for moderator effects.

Comment: It certainly does not account for moderator effects other than method variance. Other methods (and study design features!) are necessary for estimation of moderation. On the other hand, latent factors are "measured without error" in a common factor measurement model; this is a primary utility of CFA. I feel I should add that reliability, validity, and moderation are very distinct concepts, yet very difficult to disambiguate. My own understanding of their distinctions has taken about a decade to consolidate, and remains incomplete.